# Function to Determine Portfolio Volatility - Python Function Syntax

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

Can anyone spot the problem with this function?:

```
def port_vol(weights):
    return np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, data.cov() *12, weights))
```

I get the following error:

```
def port_vol(weights):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Check the previous line of code before the `def` for a missing parentheses.

Comment: How did you know?  Thank you John Gordon

Comment: When there's a syntax error on a line of code that looks fine, that's always the answer.